# django rest_framework login system

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django and djangorestframework library to make a simple API login system. I made a ViewSet so I can easily test the API from a browser and it works just fine and it gives me an authentication token. but when I want to test it with Postman It only responds when I put username/password in the body instead of the header.

When I put username/password in the header section:

```
{
"username": [
    "This field is required."
],
"password": [
    "This field is required."
]
```

When I put username/password in the body section:

```
{
"token": "b8e01db70044631e73bddc346cbf674408905a04"
```

here is my code for login system:

```
class UserLoginApiView(ObtainAuthToken):
    """Handle creating user authentication tokens"""
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES
```

My questions are:

1. Is this the right thing to send the username/password in the body section?
2. If not, how can I change Django to accept these fields in the header section?
3. Also where should I put the authentication token for future uses? (Header or Body)
   Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, yes, you'd usually POST the username/password in the body and receive a token in return. You then put that token into the header on subsequent requests, usually into the `Authorization` header.

Comment: @deceze Thank you so much. Sorry for the delay I didn't know I can thank you this way.